# Conditionally-compiled case statement in swift

Tags: swift, conditional-compilation

I've implemented an enum statement in Swift with computed properties.  I want to add values that are conditionally compiled, e.g. only for certain configurations.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
enum Rows: Int
{
    case Row1
    case Row2
    #if DEBUG
    case Debug
    #endif

    var rowTitle: String
    {
        case Row1: return "Row 1"
        case Row2: return "Row 2"
        #if DEBUG
        case Debug: return "Debug"
        #endif
    }
}
```

This does't seem to be supported as I get the following error message on the case statement within the switch statement:

> 'case' label can only appear inside a 'switch' statement

Is there a way to do this in Swift?

Thanks,
***David***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional compilation of enum cases now works as of Swift 4.

```
enum Foo {
    case bar

    #if DEBUG
    case baz
    #endif
}

let bar = Foo.bar

#if DEBUG
let baz = Foo.baz
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2) in Swift. There's no way to currently do conditional compiling inside a switch.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for conditional compilation looks correct. However, when I paste your code into a playground, I get multiple errors. The first is at the line beginning with `var rowTitle`, and the error is "Enums may not contain stored properties".

Comment: Sorry, the equal sign shouldn't have been there.  The syntax should now be correct.

Comment: Yes, so now the issue is that you are using `case` inside a property definition, not inside a `switch` statement. You can't do that. The issue is not with the conditional compilation.

Comment: I'm confused.  How is the `case` inside a property definition?  Is #if DEBUG actually a form of a closure declaration?

Answer (score 0):

This is a version of your code that is syntactically correct for the implementation of the computed variable `rowTitle`:

```
enum Rows: Int
{
    case Row1
    case Row2

    var rowTitle: String {
            switch self {
            case Row1:
                return "Row 1"
            case Row2:
                return "Row 2"
        }
    }
}
```

Said that, this is probably what you meant in your question ... but does not work:

```
enum Rows: Int
{
    case Row1
    case Row2
    #if DEBUG
    case Debug
    #endif

    var rowTitle: String {
        switch self {
        case Row1:
            return "Row 1"
        case Row2:
            return "Row 2"
        }
        #if DEBUG
            switch self {
            case Debug:
            return "Debug"
            default:
            break
            }
        #endif
    }
}
```

The compiler will not give you any error, but you will not be able to use the `Debug` case.

Comment: The first example you gave is correct if I don't want any conditionally-compiled cases.  The second example won't compile because the first switch isn't exhaustive.  Also, I want to avoid default cases because I want the compiler to give me an error if I add a new case but forget to handle it in the switch statement.